# if-throw precondition check effectiveness and the DRY principle

Tags: c++, exception, assert, dry, preconditions

A lot of internet resources insist on checking preconditions in API functions via `if (something_is_wrong) throw Exception{}` instead of `assert(!something_is_wrong)` and I see some good points in it. However, I'm afraid such usage may result in doubling the same checks:

```
void foo(int positive) {
  if (positive < 1) {
    throw std::invalid_argument("param1 must be positive");
  }
}
void caller() {
  int number = get_number_somehow();
  if (number >= 1) {
    foo(number);
  }
}
```

will probably execute like

```
int number = get_number_somehow();
if (number >= 1) {
  if (number < 1) {
    throw std::invalid_argument("param must be positive");
  }
}
```

unless the call will actually be inlined and optimized by cutting out one of the `if`s, I guess. Besides, writing the check twice (in `foo()` and in `caller()`) might be violating the DRY rule. Therefore, maybe I should go for

```
void caller() {
  int number = get_number_somehow();
  try {
    foo(number);
  } catch (std::invalid_argument const&) {
    // handle or whatever
  }
}
```

to evade repeating myself with those precondition checks, providing a bit of performance and a lot of maintainability in case of a function contract change.

However, I can't always apply such logic. Imagine `std::vector` having only `at()` but not `operator[]`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < vector.size(); ++i) {
  bar(vector.at(i)); // each index is checked twice: by the loop and by at()
}
```

This code results in extra O(N) checks! Isn't it too much? Even if it is optimized out the same way as above, what about such situations with indirect calls or long functions, which probably won't be inlined?

So, should my program be written according to the rules below?

- if an API function probably won't be inlined or is expected to be called a lot of times with checks on the call site (see the `vector` example), `assert()` its preconditions (inside it);
- try-catch throwing functions instead of checking their preconditions before the call (the latter seems to break DRY).

If not, why?

Comment: One way to think about it: The Y is yourself. If you use a black-box API, and your calls check for things that the API will, you haven't really violated DRY, since you didn't repeat yourself.  You could still care about performance, but that's something different. DRY is about code maintainability

Comment: @LouFranco OK; so, if the contract of the called function changes, all the callers will have to change their precondition checks - unmaintainable. If the precondition check is in the function fully, everything shall be fine.

Comment: While we're talking about DRY, look up (Liskov) Substitutability. A contract should only change such that it relaxes preconditions.  Your check might be too strict, but it would still work.

Comment: @LouFranco as far as I know, LSP is about polymorphic calls. Anyway, doesn't my approach allow to make the contract more strict (I'm not talking about subclasses right now)?

Comment: It was defined for that, but it is a general concept that applies to code maintenance. Think of the next version as a subclass of the previous version -- it should be substitutable into programs that were written for the old one.

Comment: Your approach allows you to not have a contract at all, which is better. Never make a contract more strict if you can, but if you can define APIs that don't need contracts, that's fine.

Comment: @LouFranco though, I don't see many programs written this way :D Has nobody discovered it? No, probably there's something wrong with the approach itself...

Comment: In the language I use everyday (Swift), `throw` is extremely cheap and safe (and therefore encouraged in API design even for common errors). That is not the case in C++ -- it is extremely hard to write exception-safe code and I would not encourage using it as s default, pervasive mechanism -- unless it was coupled with extremely safe practices (smart pointers, RAII, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, there are two separate things you are talking about: DRY and performance.

DRY is about code maintenance and structure, and doesn't really apply to code you can't control. So, if the API is a black-box, and there happens to be code inside of it that you can't change, but you need to have separately, then I wouldn't think of it as not DRY to repeat it in your code.  Y is Yourself.

But, you could still care about performance. If you measure a performance problem then fix it with whatever makes sense -- even if it's anti-DRY (or it's ok if it is).

But, if you control both sides (the API and the client) and you really want a pure, no-repeat, performant solution, then there's a pattern something like this pseudocode.  I don't know the name, but I think of it as "Proof Providing"

```
let fn = precondition_check(myNum)
if fn != nil {
    // the existence of fn is proof that myNum meets preconditions
    fn()
}
```

The API func `precondition_check` returns a function that captures the `myNum` in it and doesn't need to check if it meets preconditions because it was only created if it did.